# ProcesingJS to Python translation: map function

Tags: python, processing

I'm trying to convert some projesingjs code to python:

```
float m = map(d,0,100,0,maxspeed);
```

I believe the map function gets the value from 0 to 100 and than replaces that with a range from d to maxspeed.

Is there something like that in python?

Comment: Do you want to use the python plug-in for [processing](https://processing.org/)?

Comment: I wasnt aware there was one, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://james-ramsden.com/map-a-value-from-one-number-scale-to-another-formula-and-c-code/)

```
public double MapValue(double a0, double a1, double b0, double b1, double a)
{
    return b0 + (b1 - b0) * ((a-a0)/(a1-a0));
}
```

Which translates to Python:

```
def MapValue( a0, a1, b0, b1, a ):
    return b0 + ( b1 - b0 ) * ( ( a - a0 ) / ( a1 - a0 ) )
```

Where `b` is the range you want to remap to and `a` is the value and it's range.